# To check if age is not less than 13 years in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please guide me through javascript function, which will fetch me year difference between current date and date entered by user

I have tried this, but it doesnot keep in count leap years

```
var yearOld=2000
var dateOld=11
var mnthOld=1;
var currendDate=new Date(); // 9 - jan - 2013

var oldDate=new Date(yearOld,mnthOld-1,dateOld);

var timeDiff =currendDate-oldDate ;

var diffDays = timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365);
```

Result is coming 13.00789 something where it should come less than 13

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/learn-how-to-use-javascript-dates-and-leap-years.html#fbid=In71sGbSgo2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function getAge(birthDateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(birthDateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}

if(getAge("27/06/1989") >= 18) {
    alert("You have 18 or more years old!");
}
```

Comment: It seems it depends on user agent settings of date format. It doesn't work for the US date format mm/dd/yyyy. But thank you for the idea

Answer (score 5):

If you have good amount of Date related operations, consider using MomentJS http://momentjs.com/ . Check the first two examples there and i guess they fit your question.

### UPDATE:

MomentJS is not recommended anymore by their own declaration.

But just in case someone is curious about the solution using moment, this will work:

```
moment().diff(moment('2000'), 'years', 1) < 13
```

This will return false obviously, this is 2024 and the question was in 2013.

Comment: That library looks promising! I've been using date.js but it seems like it is not properly supported now, so if I ever need it again I'll look into it!

Comment: We're using it in a fairly complex application with AngularJS. It's very comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. Get current date
// 2. Add 13 to the year in DOB.
// 3. check if current year is less than dob-year. If not person is older than 13 years
// 4. And so on check for month and date

var date_of_birth = '2015-12-26' // example DOB
var is_13 = true; // flag for 13 

dob = date_of_birth.trim(); // trim spaces form DOB
y = parseInt(dob.substr(0,4)); // fetch year using substr() from DOB
m = parseInt(dob.substr(5,2)); // fetch month using substr() from DOB
d = parseInt(dob.substr(8,2)); // fetch date using substr() from DOB
// the above logic can change depending on the format of the input DOB

var r = new Date(); // Gets current Date

if(r.getFullYear() <= (parseInt(y) + 13)){ 
       if((r.getMonth()+1) <= m){
            if(r.getDate() < d){
                is_13 = false;
                console.log('less than 13');
}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
// millisecs * secs * mins * hrs * days (inclu. leap)
msecsInYear = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25;
```

Note: Statically not correct, but is mathematically correct!
Will cover leap year cases.